# set due date in GET request rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am doing such a request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events?interval=1d
```

OR

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/​events?due={timestamp}
```

My EventsController

```
def index
    if params[:interval]
        @events = current_user.events.where(:time => Time.now..Time.now + params[:interval].to_i.day)
    elsif params[:due]
       #I need some code here
    else
        @events = current_user.events
    end
    render json: @events
end
```

How to configure controller to make GET “​/events?due={timestamp}” work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@events = current_user.events.where("time < ?", params[:due])
```

Answer (score 0):

if Due date is the exact time then you can do :

```
@events = current_user.events.where(time: params[:due])
```